# Barcode Number required in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports 2011.For a field When i changed to bar code(Ascii 39) it is giving bar code but i need corresponding number also below of bar code.

Please help how to corresponding get number below bar code.

Comment: Just to clear up a few things, in the database your barcode is stored as an integer, yes? If so, at what stage is this converted to ASCII 39, in crystal or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi Alec in crystal it is converting

Answer (score 0):

If this has been set up conventionally, using Code39 you should simply drag the barcode DB field underneath your barcode and set the font to something more regular to display the barcode number.